# Apply quantifiers on capture groups

Tags: .net, regex

Please consider the following input string:

> X=Y
>   Z=U
>   Q=P
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
>   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

I'm wondering if it's possible capture the following with a regex one liner:

> **left**: X 
>   **right**: Y 
>  
>   **left**: Z 
>   **right**: U 
>   **left**: Q 
>   **right**: P
>   
>   **text**: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry.  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500s

The idea is that there's a bunch of lines that have a specific format followed by a "\r\n" and some text after that. I want to capture each of the key value pairs (in this example) and the text separately.

Capturing the structured data is easy enough (and just an example here):

```
(?:^(?<left>\S+)=(?<right>\S)\n)
```

But I cannot figure out how to specify something like:

"Keep capturing this pattern until the first empty line, after that take everything and capture it to "text".

It's easy enough to solve this problem using code, but I'm really interested in learning if it's even possible with nothing but a Regex one liner.

Comment: Well the output is the second quoted text block, but the answer by m.buettner really explains exactly what I was trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in .NET (and only there) you can repeat capturing groups, and get captures from each repetition:

```
^               # anchor pattern to the beginning of the string
(?:             # non-capturing group for a single x=y line
  (?<left>\S+)  # match and capture left-hand side
  =
  (?<right>\S+) # match and capture right-hand side
  \n
)+              # repeat
\n              
(?<text>.*)     # match the remainder of the string
$               # anchor pattern to the end of the string (not really necessary)
```

Make sure to use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` and `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

If your `Match` object is  called `m`, then you can now retrieve:

```
m.Groups["left"].Captures  // for a list of all left-hand sides
m.Groups["right"].Captures // for a list of all right-hand sides
m.Groups["text"].Value     // for the remainder of the string
```